# Is there an efficient way to insert n items into an n^2 sized heap

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

I am aware of a O(n) algorithm for constructing a new heap of n items, this is better than repeatedly inserting into an empty heap which takes O(nlogn). I would like to know if there is something similar for inserting a group of n items into an existing heap. Rather than using repeated insertion, is there something more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Depends. You can build a heap of the additional items ($O(n)$) and merge them - [($O(\log^2{n})$) with standard binary heaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1659205), [faster with others, e.g. Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) (note the discrepancy to the claim attributed to Sack&Strothotte).

Comment: I do think the use of $n^2$ for one and $n$ for the other size unfortunate.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say you know of an algorithm for "inserting n items into a heap", but you want an algorithm for "inserting a group of n items into a heap".  What's the difference?  What distinction are you trying to make?  What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?